# Error when using UIActionSheet and Three20

Tags: iphone, three20, uiactionsheet

In a project I'm using Three20 for some of the code (not using the `TTNavigator` or some advanced features, only a few things).

When I try to create an `UIActionSheet`, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The code that triggers it is as follows (on a `UIViewController`)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Is Anyone Injured?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

As soon as I run this code, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, and the stack points to the method called `- (CGRect)frameWithKeyboardSubtracted:(CGFloat)plusHeight`

inside Three20's `UIViewAdditions.m`.

I commented out the method, and then got an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` instead, but this time in the method called `- (NSDictionary *)userInfoForKeyboardNotification`. Again, commented that out, and now failed in another method of `UIViewAdditions.m`.

Did anyone run into this issue? I've tried debugging with `NSZombieEnabled`, but it was not the cause (no messages were sent to zombie objects).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by checking on each of the Three20 projects the "Build Active Architectures Only" checkbox. It seems to be a magical setting for several Three20 related errors...
[image]